# Did anyone use xbox wireless controller for navigation?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, navigation, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the tutorial here
http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick

```
rostest@rostest-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ rosparam set joy_node/dev "/dev/input/js0"
rostest@rostest-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun joy joy_node
[ INFO] [1490892165.561084240]: Opened joystick: /dev/input/js0. deadzone_: 0.050000.
```

rostest@rostest-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic echo joy

showing nothing..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258272/did-anyone-use-xbox-wireless-controller-for-navigation?/) by [Rezwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29875/rezwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen some joysticks that only send updates when you move the controls, so you may want to try pushing buttons or moving the joystick.

You can also confirm that you have the correct device with jstest:

```
jstest /dev/input/js0
```

This will confirm that the hardware and the Linux driver for your joystick is working, and that you have the right device node. Some mice, keyboards and laptops present a joystick-style software interface, so your joystick may actually be /dev/input/js1 or a higher number. If multiple js files exist, try all of them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rezwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29875/rezwan/) on 2017-04-11**:
Thanks.
Now Xbox controller is detected but axis values are fixed and can not be changed by moving axis in Xbox controller.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6zSx9_L3o9aVFJiMTlWM2NULXM